# E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'Self'

Tags: delphi, anonymous-methods

When I run the following code I get `E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'Self'`.

```
type
  TLookupTable = record
    FData: TArray<TOtherRec>;
    procedure ReverseLeftToRight;
  end;

procedure TLookupTable.ReverseLeftToRight;
begin
  Parallel.For(0, Length(FData)-1).NoWait.Execute(procedure(i: integer) begin
    FData[i]:= FData[i].ReverseLeftRight;
  end); {for i}
end;
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `var` parameters (including hidden var parameters to `Self`) do not get captured. However, we do not want to **copy** the record, that would be useless, because then our method would not work.

The trick is to make the hidden `self` parameter explicit.
If it's a class, then it's easy (`var S:= Self`), if not you'll have to declare a pointer to your record.

```
procedure TLookupTable.ReverseLeftToRight;
type 
  PLookupTable = ^TLookupTable;
var
  S: PLookupTable;
begin
  S:= @Self;
  Parallel.For(0, Length(FData)-1).NoWait.Execute(procedure(i: integer) begin
    S.FData[i]:= S.FData[i].ReverseLeftRight;
  end); {for i}
end;
```

Now the compiler no longer complains.
(Note that I'm using the implicit syntax for `S^.xyz`).

**Delphi Rio**
Using a inline var declaration as shown below, does not work.

```
  //S: PLookupTable;
begin
  var S:= @Self; //inline declaration
  Parallel.For(0, Length(FData)-1).NoWait.Execute(procedure(i: integer) begin
    S.FData[i]:= S.FData[i].ReverseLeftRight;
  end); {for i}
```

This generates: `E2018 Record, object or class type required`.
I guess the inline `@Self` gets resolved to a generic pointer, which is a shame, because there is enough info to infer the correct type for the inline variable.

**Asynchronous issues**
If you're executing the code using a Async (`.NoWait`) thread/task, then it might be better to put `FData` in the local variable. FData, being a dynamic array, is already a pointer (so no copying will take place, just a ref count). And dynamic arrays do not have Copy-on-Write semantics, so the original will get updated.
As is, the `Self` record might go out of scope whilst the code is running, because the pointer operation `S:= @Self` does not cause the reference count on FData to increase). This might cause an access violation (or worse).
Taking a reference to FData causes its refcount to go up, meaning it cannot go out of scope prematurely.

Comment: Personally I would rather put `FData` into a local variable and capture that. That also ensures that the captured `Self` does not run out of scope if the closure would be executed asynchronously.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, good point, I keep forgetting that dynamic arrays are not CoW.